# Android, Image buttons are not density independent

Tags: android, user-interface, imagebutton

I followed the guidelines presented in the Android docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and created image buttons at 36x36pixels, 48x48pixels and 72x72pixels then upped these in the ldpi, mdpi,hdpi folders... but when i change the screen resolutions in the xml-layout-creation place in Eclipse... the image button sizes keep changing :(

Is there some other setting I am supposed to change?

My XML is very simple, for example:

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/level1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:onClick="button_clicked1">
```

(full file: http://pastebin.com/nyh2BMFE)

Please advise!

EDIT:
Ok, added the default icon that Android creates in each directry and that too is not scaling so well like the rest of the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing resolution is not a guarantee that density changes, since density is also a function of the screen size. The safest way would be to create AVDs with the required resolutions AND densities.

Comment: Like i mentioned, putting in various dpi folders is not a guarantee that they will be the same. It is better to layout using proportions and have the image scaled to the right proportion (in code).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a DIP unit i.e. Density Independent Pixels.

If it works then please provide me some feedback.